Supermicro power distribution board with 12VHPWR
I have a Supermicro 2U chassis with a power distributor board PDB-PT826-S4824 in it. And it should have support for the nVidia L40 graphics card.
It has 2 8-pin +12V connectors for powering PCIe devices.
But the nVidia L40 GPU has a 12VHPWR (16-pin) connector. How can I connect this graphics card to the power supply.
Do I need an other power distribution board? Or is there a conversion cable available?

I have found this cable: CBL-PWEX-0962Y-50. Will this work?
